# How to find a new HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 13.04

I have only shell access to a machine (I'm remote and I `ssh` in) but I can `sudo`. I am told by someone on-site that he has added a hard disk drive to the machine. I need to mount it (which I know how to do), but first I need to find it. I know nothing more. How do I find it? Where is it? And if there's more than one HDD there (wherever I'm finding this unmounted drive), then how do I know which is the new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a list of hdd(s), type `lsblk`.

Comment: This is a very useful command...

Comment: +1: many thanks: this seems to work, and shows a good amount of information. It doesn't show the new HDD, however. Perhaps the guy who says he added it to the machine didn't in fact.